# How to set validity of transcluded element that contains a model?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a directive that takes a form input, and wraps that input with arbitrary HTML.

So this:

`<input ng-model="myModel" required>`

Becomes:

```
<div>
  some markup here
  <input ng-model="myModel" required>
</div>
```

What is the correct way to update the validity and value of my model from within my directive? Normally I would require `ngModelController` and call `$setValidity` and `$setViewValue`, however, since `ng-model` exists on my transcluded element and not on my directive's top level element, it seems I can't access `ngModelController`.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in these scenarios is to make your directive itself implement `ngModelController`.

Check out "Implementing custom form controls (using ngModel)" section on this page: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Another trick, if you have a form element, you can get a hold of the `ngModelController` instances if there is an error key in $error:

```
  angular.forEach($scope.myForm.$error, function(o, name) {
        for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
            o[i].$setValidity(name, false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It seems that if I use the approach in the example you referenced, I can't leverage the built in ```require``` validators, etc?

Comment: That is a nice trick. However, my directive has no knowledge of its containing form.